# Bash. Finding specific text in files using find, cat and grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have thousands of folders filled with old junk that I need to make sense of. Namely I need to **find all files containing specific text** in files using mask. But if I do it using **grep -R "mask"** it churns all that junk and machine is stuck as a result.
I want to pipe find and cat results to grep but can't find right way.

```
a=$(find ./ -name "*.txt")
for i in $a; do
  cat $i | grep "string" >> result.txt
done
```

Something like that, but it doesn't  seems to work. Where am I stupid?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but what is your goal here? If you just want to get file names, you could do something like `find ./ -name "*.txt" -exec grep -l "string" {} \; >> result.txt`

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `cat`.
`grep "string" $i` is faster.

You don't need `find` either.

The command you need is:

```
grep -r -l "string" --include="*.txt" .
```

It runs faster than any combination of `find` and `grep` because it runs only one process.

The arguments:

- `-r` tells `grep` to process the input directory (`.`) recursively.
- `-l` tells it to suppress its normal output and echo only the name of the matching files. It runs faster because it stops on the first match in each file.
- `"string"` is the text you are searching.
- `--include="*.txt"` limits the search to the files whose name match the pattern. The quotes around `*.txt"` are needed; without them the shell expands `*.txt` to the list of matching files in the current directory.
- `.` is the directory where to search for files; the current directory in this example.

Comment: in `grep "string" file`, "string" is not a literal string, it's a regular expression, so you should say `grep "regexp" file` instead for clarity.